# extjs 5 how to bind store to modal window and grid

Tags: extjs, mvvm

The case is pretty common, when you dbl click a cell in a grid, modal window with a form appearing, there you make changes, click the Save button, and having the store in a grid updated. In 4-th I did it via loadRecord from grid to form, and then used set-method to apply changes to grid store. Now I'm trying to do it with MVVM approach, and having some stucks. Because when I set the same VM to the grid and form, after form destroying (Save or Cancel button) the VM is also destroying, and the app ruining. And so, we can't use one VM instanse in multiple components. We have to place it in a container, where a grid and a form are. All official examples are of such a type. 
And the question is, if anybody resolved this issue?
[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/a1k)
[answer from sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?291472)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to **user1638582**'s answer, my own solution was to add selected record to ViewModel of form:

```
var form = Ext.create('Plus.view.FormbetV',{
   viewModel:{ 
       data:{
          currentRec:this.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0]
       }
   }
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/jp6

Answer (score 4):

ExtJs 5 ViewModel has nested structure for components, all sub-objects can to use parent's ViewModel. So you could try to add window object to ViewController view:

```
var form = Ext.create('Plus.view.FormbetV');
var window = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
    frame: true,
    width: 350,
    height: 200,
    modal: true,
    layout: 'fit'
});
window.add(form);
this.getView().add(window); // <--- add parent 'scope'
window.show();
```

And don't forget to remove this code:

```
//var viewModel = Ext.getCmp('gridbet').getViewModel();
//this.setViewModel(viewModel);
```

It works for me, but in this case windows size will be limited by grid size.

Comment: I like your solution, but it seems that there is a problem with window title- it's not seen.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, interesting way!
To fix window title we could use `height: 300` for grid and then remove formulars for _gridbet_ ViewModel. But anyways modal window will be broken.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the examples, the "Data Binding -> Isolated Child Sessions" seems to be what we're looking for:

http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#binding-child-session

Answer (score 1):

Have you read through [this blog post](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-5-mvc-mvvm-and-more), in which an [MVVM example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5kn) for the grid is used?

Comment: Yes, thanks, but it seems to me that it is not pure MVVM approach, but combined with MVC, since you use global controller, and don't bind store to the grid with 'bind' directive. I was interested in a way how to bind data in modal form and grid via common VM. Since according to docs it's impossible.

Comment: Per Evan's point in your forum thread, two components cannot share the same ViewModel.